# How to install nginx mod lua on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: nginx, yum, lua, amazon-linux-2

I have an Amazon Linux 2 machine. I have installed `NGINX` with

```
amazon-linux-extras install nginx1.12
```

How can I install `nginx-mod-http-lua`?

I have tried:

```
yum search lua
```

and no packages are listed which look like what I want.

This page https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/lua/ says to run `yum install nginx-plus-module-lua`, but I get `No package nginx-plus-module-lua available.`

Answer (score 2):

Installation procedure that you are referring to is for NGINX+

You can try with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357732/adding-lua-module-to-nginx

Comment: Is there an `nginx-mod-http-lua` RPM linked from that answer? I can't find it amongst all the links about how to install rpms, if so.

Comment: No there is no rpm, you need to follow procedure described

Comment: So install from source only. OK, thanks!

Comment: Please find package here - https://centos.pkgs.org/7/puias-unsupported-x86_64/nginx-mod-http-lua-0.10.7-1.sdl7.x86_64.rpm.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Amazon Linux 2 is largely a clone of CentOS/RHEL, you may have your luck with RPM packages for those systems:

```
yum install https://extras.getpagespeed.com/release-el7-latest.rpm
yum install nginx-module-lua
```

Comment: if you pay their subscription ..